# Underscore.js _.map function : skip a value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscore.js `_.map` function on an array of objects, to get an array with a property of each object. That's the usual scenario, so :

```
var finalArray = _.map(myArray, function(obj) {
    return obj.myProperty;
});
```

But in some cases I need that *nothing* be added in the array. It could be something like :

```
var finalArray = _.map(myArray, function(obj) {
    if (!obj.ignore) {
        return obj.myProperty;
    }
});
```

The result of this is that an `undefined` value is pushed into the array, which is not the same as not pushing anything at all.

Is there a way for the map function not to push a value, or do I need to post-process my `finalArray` to remove the unwanted `undefined`'s?

Comment: I think you should consider choosing as best answer that of Thomas Eschemann, because it loops through all elements of the Array just once as asked in "Is there a way for the map function not to push a value", the primary goal for this question. And the answer is use reduce() instead of map().

Comment: The currently chosen answer is for the second part of the question "do I need to post-process my finalArray to remove the unwanted undefined's?". And the answer to that second part is: No, you don't need to post-process finalArray(), you need to use reduce() instead of map() to avoid post-processing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you should use _.filter() before _.map()

```
var filteredArray = _.filter(myArray,function(obj) {
     return !obj.ignore;
});

var finalArray = _.map(filteredArray, function(obj) {
    return obj.myProperty;
});
```

Comment: **after**, not _before_

Comment: as foucdeg describe his problem, there is no need to transform the inputs to decide wether they should be excluded or not. filter **before** is then better in term of performance

Answer (score 31):

You could use reduce:

```
myArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    if (!obj.ignore) {
        acc.push(obj.myProperty);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

or with lodash:

```
_.reduce(myArray, function (acc, obj) {
  if (!obj.ignore) {
    acc.push(obj.myProperty);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it loops through all elements just once as asked by @foucdeg "Is there a way for the map function not to push a value". The answer is use reduce() instead of map().

Comment: Agreed this should be the accepted answer - loops only once. Also note that this works with `underscorejs`, not sure why `lodash` is mentioned here since OP's asking about `underscorejs`. Also underscore's doc is kind of confusing : "reduce boils down a list of values into a single value." where in this case the single value is an array...

Answer (score 14):

This can be done using Underscore methods alone, [points-free style](http://scott.sauyet.com/Javascript/Talk/FunctionalProgramming/#slide-98):

```
var finalArray = _.chain(myArray)
    .reject('ignore')
    .pluck('myProperty')
    .value();
```

Comment: I love this approach. It's simply clean and very readable. (Also *pure functional, monadic thinking*)

Comment: @Pavlo You need an explicit `.chain` with Underscore and you can simply use `.reject('ignore')` instead of `.reject(_.property('ignore'))`. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/2gpvws1u/

Answer (score 5):

`.map` will map out a new value to the array, you can use `.filter` to filter the array. FYI you can use `.pluck` to map a property from an object:

```
_.chain(myArray).filter(function(obj) { return !obj.ignore; }).pluck('myProperty').value();
```

You can also use `.where` like this:

```
_.chain(myArray).where({ignore: false}).pluck('myProperty').value();
```

Or:

```
_.pluck(_.where(myArray, {ignore: false}), 'myProperty');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using lodash's **`compact()`**.  It creates an array with all falsey values removed. Thus, the values `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined`, and `NaN` are removed.

https://lodash.com/docs#compact

I'm using it—it's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

**So this means you want to filter, then map your array.**

To do this in `underscore` way, you will need to pass your array into this pipeline:

> myArray --> **filter** --> **map** --> finalArray

```
var isIncluded = function(obj){
    return !obj.ignore
}
var takeProperty = function(obj){
    return obj.myProperty
}
var finalArray = _.map( _.filter(myArray, isIncluded), takeProperty  );
```

Comment: **NOTE** You can replace `takeProperty` with `_.pluck` function as @dev-null proposed in another answer.

Comment: @foucdeg Underscore makes you think in smaller units rather than *one fat function which includes multiple jobs*. You are encouraged to write small unit of function, join them in sequential operations to make a bigger unit of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  This one makes use of the compose function in underscore.  Why compose?  compose is backed by Category theory in Mathematics.  This way is also point-free.

```
var pluckMyProp = function(array) {
    return _.pluck(array, 'myProperty')
}

var reject = function(array) {
    return _.reject(array, function(element) {
        return element['ignore'] === true
    })
}

var finalArray = _.compose(pluckMyProp, reject)
var data = [{myProperty: 1, ignore: false}, {ignore: true}, {myProperty: 2}]


finalArray(data) //=> [1,2]
```

Comment: To convert the above from underscore to lodash, change `_.pluck` to `_map` & `_.compose` to `_.flowRight`.